# How can i add chars to proceed string to custom ending?

Tags: php, string

I have string template, like `+7 (***) ***-**-**` and input vars like `+7 (123)` or `+7 (123) 45`. I need to complete input var to mask template, it must be `+7 (123) ***-**-**` and `+7 (123) 45*-**-**` (for upper examples).

I know about `str_pad`, but it's didn't help for this task. Google didn't help me to.

Comment: inputs can have `+7 (***) 45*-**-**`?

Comment: Have you tried something? Show your current code/attempt.